# Neo4j - get ID, Labels properties from the resultset

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate to get the result from the Neo4j.
I want "ID" of the node as well as the "Labels" which is present in the node but I only got the "Properties".

This is the sample sql:

```
MATCH path = (n:NodeABC)-[]-(i:NodeXYZ)
WHERE n.name = 'iqwe' 
RETURN n as instance, relationships(path)
```

I want ID and Labels as well in the resultset. How to get it?

The tech stack is:

- Neo4j - 5
- Java - 17
- SpringBoot - 3.2

Thanks,

Atul

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

You need to write the query to return the specific result.

```
MATCH path = (n:NodeABC)-[]-(i:NodeXYZ)
WHERE n.name = 'iqwe' 
RETURN { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), properties: properties(n) } as instance, relationships(path)
```

Instead of return 'n', you need to specify like this '

> { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), properties: properties(n) }

'

Thanks,

Atul